# Why do I need the time.sleep(x) function in this code for it to work?

Tags: python, time, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time
import snake

MOVE_DISTANCE = 20


UP = 90
DOWN = 270
LEFT = 180
RIGHT = 0


class InitialSnake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.number_x = 0
        self.snake_first = []
        self.create_snake()
        self.actual_snake = self.snake_first[0]

    def create_snake(self):
        for number in range(3):
            snake = Turtle(shape="square")
            snake.penup()
            snake.color("white")
            snake.goto(self.number_x, 0)
            self.number_x -= 20
            self.snake_first.append(snake)

    def move(self):
        for segments_num in range(len(self.snake_first) - 1, 0, -1):
            self.snake_first[segments_num].goto(self.snake_first[segments_num - 1].xcor(),
                                                self.snake_first[segments_num - 1].ycor())
        self.snake_first[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)

    def up(self):
        if self.actual_snake.heading() != DOWN:
            self.snake_first[0].setheading(UP)
    def down(self):
        if self.actual_snake.heading() != UP:
            self.snake_first[0].setheading(DOWN)
    def left(self):
        if self.actual_snake.heading() != RIGHT:
            self.snake_first[0].setheading(LEFT)
    def right(self):
        if self.actual_snake.heading() != LEFT:
            self.snake_first[0].setheading(RIGHT)


my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
my_screen.bgcolor("black")
my_screen.title("Snake Game")
my_screen.tracer(0)
snake_1 = snake.InitialSnake()

#snake_here.create_snake()

game_is_on = True

my_screen.listen()
my_screen.onkey(snake_1.up, "Up")
my_screen.onkey(snake_1.down,"Down")
my_screen.onkey(snake_1.left,"Left")
my_screen.onkey(snake_1.right,"Right")

while game_is_on:
    my_screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    snake_1.move()


my_screen.exitonclick()
```

I did not really understand the concept of the tracer and the update and how this is linked to the sleep function. I understand that when the tracer is called and turned off, it will not refresh the screen until you call the update() function. But shouldn't it still work without time.sleep(0.1) since this is just creating a short delay before the next functions get called. Can someone help me please to understand this? Thanks in advance (:

Comment: I think I saw this problem in some question long time ago - but I can be wrong.

Comment: I don't know if this code use `threads` or something similar but sometimes one code may run in separated thread and other code can be executed before first code finish job - so it may has to wait for code in thread. And `sleep` can be the easier method for this.

Comment: or maybe your code runs very, very fast and snake already left screen and you can't see it. You may try to use `print()` to see snake current position.

Comment: I used `print()` and after starting code and snake code is almost `125700` - so your code runs too fast and it needs `sleep` to slow down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `print()` to see snake position

```
while game_is_on:
    my_screen.update()
    snake_1.move()

    print(snake_1.snake_first[0].ycor(), snake_1.snake_first[0].xcor())
```

then you will see it moves very, very fast and it left screen - and you simply can't see it.

On my very old computer after few milliseconds its positon was `(0, 125700)`. Probably on the newest computer it would be much bigger value.

So this code use `sleep()` to slow down `snake` and to move it with the same speed on all computers.

---

**BTW:**

I would use `turtle` method to repeate code

```
def game_loop():
    snake_1.move()
    my_screen.update()
    my_screen.ontimer(game_loop, 100)  # repeate after 100ms (0.1s)

# start loop       
game_loop()
```

because `sleep` may blocks some code and `ontimer` was created for non-blocking delay.